# Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the `test-network` to deploy my chaincode as follows:

```
./network.sh up createChannel -c mychannel -ca

./network.sh deployCC -ccn mychaincode -ccp /.../mychaincode/ -ccl javascript
```

When the network is up, I notice the folder `.../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations` is created.  So, I copied the following `json` files to my nodejs project's `config` folder:

```
.../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.json

.../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/connection-org2.json
```

So when I submit transaction, I use `Org1` for organization and get the connection profile from `.../config/connection-org1.json` which is the one I copied over to my nodejs project folder.
Then I got the following error upon calling `contract.submitTransaction("CallMyMethod", ...args)`:

```
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0.org1.example.com due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true 
    at checkState (/.../mynodejsproject/node_modules/@grpc/grpcjs/build/src/client.js:77:26) 
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/.../mynodejsproject/node_modules/@grpc/grpcjs/build/src/channel.js:525:17) 
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) { connectFailed: true }
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: ServiceEndpoint grpcs://localhost:7051 reset connection failed :: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - no discovery results
```

If I submit a transaction via command line from the `test-network` directory as follows, everything is fine.

```
export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"Args":["CallMyMethod"]}'
```

However, when calling from my nodejs app, I got that `Failed to connect before deadline` error.  I am using mac and docker desktop.  Do I need to do anything other than referring to the `connection-org1.json` which I copied from the `test-network` folder?

Comment: It appears that everytime I bring up the network, I need to re-copy the connection-org*.json from peerOrganizations folder to my config folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that tlsCACerts pem gets updated everytime you get your network down and up.

The easy fix for this should be to replace 'pem' with 'path' like below -

```
tlsCACerts:
      path: <certpath>
```

(This needs to be done for orderer and all the peers in organization)

Or you can replace the CCP file everytime you re-run your network.